# Subsearch produced 221180 results, truncating to maxout 10000

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

i have 221180 ips in csv(deattackerv1.csv)  with only one field "ip" .. where i want to check if we have any hit in splunk for that ip's in given one index .. How can we achieve that ..

below is the query .. but i am getting error as "`Subsearch produced 221180 results, truncating to maxout 10000.`"

```
index=*_abc  | search [| inputlookup deattackerv1.csv | table ip | rename ip as src_ip] | stats count by src_ip,index
```

Note:- src_ip is one column in index=*_abc .

I have tried below as well ..

```
index=*_abc 
| stats count as eventcount by src_ip,index
| append [| inputlookup deattackerv1.csv | table ip | rename ip as src_ip]
| eventstats values(index) as indexes
| eval index=if(isnull(index),indexes,index)
| table eventcount src_ip index
| mvexpand index
| stats count as sourcecount values(eventcount) as eventcount by src_ip index
| where sourcecount > 1
| table src_ip eventcount index
```

but getting error as
INFO MESSAGES:

```
[subsearch]: Subsearch produced 221180 results, truncating to maxout 50000.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close

Do this instead:

```
index=*_abc [| inputlookup deattackerv1.csv | rename ip as src_ip] 
| stats count by src_ip,index
```

This will use the [`inputlookup`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/inputlookup) the way you want it to (ie, only match IPs that are in it)